# labeling an area using 2 variables

Tags: vba, excel

I need to label certain areas of a table. I need everything from "Run Start" to "Run End" to have a corresponding run number in a different column.

```
H (Run #)    O (Activity_code)                    S (what I need)
  1          Piping                               
  1          Run Start - TBRT                     1
  1          OPS-RIH/POOH/Trip/Wiper Trip         1
  1          OPS-Drilling                         1
  1          OPS-Surveying                        1
  1          RIG-OPS-RIH/POOH/Trip/Wiper Trip     1
  1          Run End - TART                       1
  1          OPS BHA Config
  1          Piping 
  2          Run Start - TBRT                     2
```

I still haven't fully figured out loops in VBA. Here is what I've come up with. I cant seem to find anything on this or get it working. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
For i = 2 To Worksheet1.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    If Worksheet1.Cells(i, o) = "Run S*" Then
        x = i
        If Worksheet.Cells(i, o).Value = "Run E*" Then
        Range("S" & x & ":" & "S" & i) = Range("H" & i).Value
        End If
    End If
Exit For
Next
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If in your columns you have always have "Run Start" and "Run End" to define your labels, you could just use a solution like this (I assume the three columns are "A", "B" and "C"):

```
Dim count As Integer: count = 2 'check the cell until it's empty
Dim isrunning As Boolean: isrunning = False 'controls if the run has started but not ended
Do While Range("B" & count) <> ""
    If isrunning = True Then
        Range("C" & count) = Range("A" & count)
        If Left(Range("B" & count),5) = "Run E" Then isrunning = False                
    Else
        If Left(Range("B" & count),5) = "Run S" Then
            Range("C" & count) = Range("A" & count)
            isrunning = True
        End If
    End If
    count = count + 1
Loop
```

Please note that:

1. This will stop when the cell in column "B" gets empty;
2. I see you want to report the number from the column "A" to the column "C" if you are between a Run Start and a Run End (included), but correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfectly and I was able to learn a little bit from it! Thanks for taking the time to look at it.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
Sub ject()
    Const what1 As String = "Run Start - TBRT"
    Const what2 As String = "Run End - TART"
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With Sheets("Sheet1") '~~> change to suit
         Dim r As Range, lr As Long
         lr = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
         Set r = .Range("A1", "C" & lr) '~~> assumes data is in A - C column
         Dim run, runs
         runs = GetFilters(r.Offset(1, 0).Resize(r.Rows.Count - 1, 1))
         For Each run In runs
            Dim str As Range, enr As Range
            r.AutoFilter 1, run
            Set str = r.Find(what1): Set enr = r.Find(what2)
            If Not str Is Nothing And Not enr Is Nothing Then _
                .Range(str, enr).Offset(0, 1).Value = run
         Next
         .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

---

```
Private Function GetFilters(source As Range)
    Dim c As Range
    If Not source Is Nothing Then
        With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
            For Each c In source.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells
                If Not .Exists(c.Value) Then .Add c.Value, c.Value
            Next
            GetFilters = .Keys
        End With
    End If
End Function
```

This ignores **RUNS** without end yet. If you want it considered, you can alter the *If statement* adding more conditions to it. HTH.

Comment: I really appreciate your help. For some reason I couldn't get this to work. This answer is a bit over my head. I was able to learn some stuff from your answer though. Thank you!

Comment: @Ryan Most parts of it needs to be adjusted to suit your needs. I provided comments on lines of code that needs your attention. If you still want to explore this answer, you can always ask and if I can, I'll help you. Glad you found an answer that best suits you :)